# Python delete xml tags and move xml tags

Tags: python, xml, tags

I am new to python and have been trying to accomplish something, and not been sucsessful so far. I am trying to open an xml, delete whole tags and their contents, and move other tags around within the xml.

Here is my original import xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package>
    <language>en-GB</language>
    <video>
        <original_spoken_locale>en-US</original_spoken_locale>
        <copyright_cline>2012 copyright</copyright_cline>
        <release_date>2012-04-23</release_date>
        <title>Amazing Film</title>
    </video>
    <provider>testprovider</provider>
</package>
```

I need to remove the `<copyright_cline>` tag and the `<title>` tag. Then I need to move the `<provider>` tag up into the `<video>` tag and position it between the `<original_spoken_locale>` and the `<release_date>` tags.

Here is the resulted export xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package>
    <language>en-GB</language>
    <video>
        <original_spoken_locale>en-US</original_spoken_locale>
        <provider>testprovider</provider>
        <release_date>2012-04-23</release_date>
    </video>
</package>
```

I have tried various solutions, nothing I completely got working.
I liked `xml.etree` module, I also tried to instal `lxml`, but couldn't get it installed, so would like to use a module that doesn't need installing. I am using `python 3.3.2.`

Although this site is an amazing source of information, my knowledge isn't enough to get a handle on it. What would really help is an example working code which I can then study and hopefully understand.
Many thanks.

Comment: I now have lxml working, so would appreciate some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bs4.BeautifulSoup`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crummy.com%2Fsoftware%2FBeautifulSoup%2F&ei=9TqsUY_KOuiTiQeV6YCYAQ&usg=AFQjCNHAxwplurFOBqg5cehWQEVKi-TuLQ&sig2=v8bssU_JNkzr-T8GnepRfA&bvm=bv.47244034,d.aGc):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package>
    <language>en-GB</language>
    <video>
        <original_spoken_locale>en-US</original_spoken_locale>
        <copyright_cline>2012 copyright</copyright_cline>
        <release_date>2012-04-23</release_date>
        <title>Amazing Film</title>
    </video>
    <provider>testprovider</provider>
</package>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
soup.copyright_cline.replace_with(soup.provider)
soup.title.extract()
print soup
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
<language>en-GB</language>
<video>
<original_spoken_locale>en-US</original_spoken_locale>
<provider>testprovider</provider>
<release_date>2012-04-23</release_date>

</video>

</package>
```

I don't see why you couldn't install the `lxml` module, but to install `BeautifulSoup` just do a simple `pip install bs4` or [download it manually](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I will certainly give it a try. Are there any exaple solutions using xml.etree, so i don't have to install any other modules, as the mac I need to run this on has restricted instal. kind regards.

Comment: OK, I think I have managed to install lxml. What would be lxml solution please?

Comment: OK, lxml all installed and working. would someone be very kind and provide an example of lxml code please?

Comment: @user2446702 Sorry mate, I don't know `lxml`. You might want to edit your question now that you got it working :)